# Мне python выдаёт ошибку "Для скобки "[" отсутствует закрывающая скобка" хотя закрывающая скобка есть, пробовал в одну строчку не помогло

Tags: python

```
walk_left = [
    player = pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/1_left.png'),
    player = pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/2_left.png'),
    player = pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/3_left.png'),
    player = pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/4_left.png')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный код должен быть такой:

```
walk_left = [
    pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/1_left.png'),
    pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/2_left.png'),
    pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/3_left.png'),
    pygame.image.load('img/Sprite/left/4_left.png')
]
```

Из списка walk_left убраны присваивания, из конца — запятая. Должно работать.